# SQLite sort by integer value

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I'm using `ActiveAndroid` library. I need to get a list of my objects sorted by the `integer` field. here is how I'm trying to do that:

```
public static List<Category> getCategories() {
    try {
        return new Select()
            .all()
            .from(Category.class)
            .orderBy("NumInRow ASC") // NumInRow is my int field
            .execute();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Absolutely ,what you have done is Correct way to order the column,it doesn't matter whether it is a int or some other data type.

Example :

```
public static List<Item> getAll(Category category) {
        // This is how you execute a query
        return new Select()
          .from(Item.class)
          .where("Category = ?", category.getId())
          .orderBy("Name ASC")
          .execute();
    }
```

**Active Android Complete Guide**
[Using Active Android](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ActiveAndroid-Guide)